# Mysterious off by-1 error

Tags: r, data-manipulation

The code that I am trying to run is:

```
library("devtools")
pull_lists <- source_gist("6f3c8adad9aded7ae5dd")
pull_lists <- pull_lists[[1]]

sha_list <- vector("list", length(pull_lists))
  for (i in 1:length(pull_lists)){
    try_default(sha_list[i] <- pull_lists[[i]]$content[[1]]$sha, default = NULL)
  }
```

Initially `pull_lists` and therefore also `sha_list` has a length of 687, but when the loop is done the length is 686. How is this possible?

Comment: Is one of the sha null?  Null isn't an element so the list would be shorter

Comment: Anyways, you could receive a similar result more efficiently using something like `lapply(pull_lists, function(x) if(length(x$content)) unlist(x$content[[1]]['sha'], use.names = F))`.

Comment: @LegalizeIt: Shouldn't the `try_default()` overcome the problem with element's being null?

Comment: @lukeA: why does your solution return 687 and mine 686?

Comment: Because, when I remember it correctly, your solution drops the last element in sha_list, which should be NULL. I don't know why. But I wouldn't bother too much, as the straight solution is preferable anyway.